# How can I auto render katex without having to use $$?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, tex, katex

I've been struggling to understand how to render Katex without having to use $$ before and after the math expression. Katex on github says I should use this:

```
<script>
    renderMathInElement(document.body);
  </script>
```

But I still need to use $$ for each line of code. How can I render the whole page as katex? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example.  If you paste this code in an HTML file and then open that file in a browser, it should render, and with no occurrences of `$$` anywhere to be found, so hopefully you can then tweak it to whatever you need.

Not sure why, but I needed to use `\\` wherever I found `\` on the Katex [function support page](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/function-support.html), so if `\\` doesn't work for you, try switching it to `\`.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="formula">f(x)</span>
  <script>
    katex.render("\\int_0^1{f(x)}", formula);
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Katex docs acknowledged the double backslash inconvenience [here](https://katex.org/docs/api.html#in-browser-rendering) and recommended to use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) if someone wishes to avoid using it.